# how to make android api key for the client mobile ip adress?

Tags: android

how to make the android api key authorized for client mobile ip address ??
because after debugging my Google map mobile application to access the details of the near places from my current location i am getting an error like
"this client ip address is not authorized to use API key".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to https://console.developers.google.com/project.
2. Select your project.
3. Click **Credentials** under **APIs and Auth** in the left menu.
4. Click **Edit allowed IPs**, and add the IP which is blocked. For testing, you can add  `0.0.0.0/0` to allow all IPs.

Comment: There is no option like edit allowed IPs ...there is option edit allowed android application...